# Killing a child process after 10 seconds - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following piece of code:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const find = spawn('find', ['.', '-type', 'f']);
const wc = spawn('wc', ['-l']);

find.stdout.pipe(wc.stdin);

wc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`Number of files ${data}`);
});

wc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

wc.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

I wanted to kill the `wc` and `find` child processes regardless after 10 seconds. I'm new to NodeJS ... how can I accomplish that?

Comment: `setTimeout(() => wc.kill(), 10000)` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms could you please make it more formal? Just call setTimeout() whenever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [process.exit](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal) to exit `entire process`. On setTimeout of 10 secs, can call `process.exit(0)`

`setTimeout(process.exit, 10*1000, 0)`

*For individual child process use kill method.*

[subprocess.kill([signal])](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal)

**Example:**

```
setTimeout(() => {
  wc.kill("SIGINFO")
}, 10*1000, 0)
```

Comment: Could you please formalize, specially the individual child process portion?

Comment: i have added link, Please check.